# Request checking account types for Banking Financial Institutions

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

we're working with the OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 APIs and would like to have checking account types provided via the API.

In Credit Union scenarios, we are successfully retrieving the desired information by setting the `https://api.banno.com/consumer/claim/shares` restricted claim in combination with the `Share records - Credit Unions` claim checkbox checked in the Banno admin portal.

In the context of Banking institutions, how can checking account type data be requested via the API?

To be clear, we’re trying to identify if a user has one checking account type vs. another. This allows us to know whether a specific user is eligible for specific benefits.

[image: Banno Admin]

Answer (score 1):

In general, you'll want to use the Consumer API's `GET /users/{userId}/accounts` endpoint to retrieve the *accountType* and *accountSubType* for each account.

The [Accounts / Details](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/accounts/details/) page has listings of the *accountType* and *accountSubType* values which are available for banks as well as for credit unions (based on the financial core).

Comment: Thanks for this info. We're getting an HTTP `200` response with an empty response body for the `GET /users/{userId}/accounts` that was suggested. Can you tell us why that might be? The `x-request-id` is `fa636580e0ca01730af5875aaa1fadf2`. Thanks!

Comment: What do you see when you log into Banno Online for that same user? Do you see the accounts? Banno Online uses the same API to retrieve the accounts. If the latest data hasn't been pulled from the core, you might want to do a Data Refresh as described in https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/guides/datarefresh/, then try retrieving the accounts via the API. (Separately, given that you got an HTTP 200 instead of HTTP 403 I'm assuming you're using the `https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/accounts.readonly` OAuth scope for the authentication.)

Comment: Thanks again for the follow up. I noticed that on the /accounts endpoint it calls out the `https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/accounts.readwrite` scope. What is that scope needed for given that the endpoint in question is a `GET` request?

Comment: @JaimeLopezJr., yes, that user has the checking account of interest shown on their online banking dashboard when they login. Just to clarify, what we're trying to do, we want to know if a user has a specific checking account type (e.g.: "SecureChecking Plus", and not "SecureChecking Free"). This worked great for Credit Unions via ShareTypes. Apparently the same can't be used for Banks.

Comment: This is our `scope` value: `openid profile email https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/accounts.readonly https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/accounts.readwrite`

Comment: Yeah, we don't have that sort of information for banks since that 'shares' stuff is very credit union-centric. That's less of an account type / subtype (in our parlance...more on that in a bit) and more of a 'financial product offering'. For our API, the account types and subtypes are defined lower on the API Reference page, and notice that they're not really the financial product offering: https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/consumer-api/api-reference/v0/accounts/details/#account-types

Comment: Separately (I know this wasn't your question) but for the OAuth scopes if an endpoint defines two scopes like `https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/accounts.readonly` and `https://api.banno.com/consumer/auth/accounts.readwrite` you only need to include 1 of those (depending on if you need read-only access or both read-and-write access). It's a logical OR instead of a logical AND. Apologies that isn't clear from how the doc is rendered. Mixing scopes for the same endpoint _might_ be causing some oddities, though, given that you're able to see data in Banno Online.

Comment: @JaimeLopezJr., thank you for the quick responses. If `shares` are CU related and type/subtype sound like it doesn't work, how can we achieve what we're attempting to do? Is there any way to get the branded name of a checking account? The Banks have provided us with 2 to 3-digit identifiers for the checking accounts we should make "eligible" for our embedded plug-in content.

Comment: I don't think using the Consumer API is going to be the way to go in your use case. The kind of information you're looking for is probably on the core itself, which would mean integrating with jXchange (for banks) and SymXchange (for credit unions) to get that kind of data (if available). See the "develop enterprise solutions" section on the JackHenry.Dev homepage.

Comment: @JaimeLopezJr. really, thank you for your responses! This impacts several of our clients. Who best should we follow-up with to figure out a solution or confirm whether your suggestion is a viable option? my email brian@econocheck.com

Comment: After asking some folks who work with jXchange, they said the 'Account Search' (https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-soap-api/api-reference/core-services/account-search/) and 'Account Inquiry'  (https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-soap-api/api-reference/core-services/account-inquiry/) APIs are going to be useful to find the information you're seeking. The inquiry has a `ProdDesc` element which should return something like `<ProdDesc>Business Checking Account</ProdDesc>` which should be what you're seeking.

Comment: Looks like the new URLs for 'Account Search' and 'Account Inquiry', are, respectively, https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-soap-api/api-reference/core-services/acctsrch/ and https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-soap-api/api-reference/core-services/acctinq/. The same `ProdDesc` element is applicable.